# Does "update_post_meta" check if value is the same before updating?

Tags: post-meta

When running the following code:

```
update_post_meta( 1, '_visibility', 'visible' );
```

Does wordpress check to see if post_id `1` key `_visable`  has a value of `visible` before writing to database?

I have an import script and I'm wondering is this would save processing time.

```
function update_post_meta_check($post_id, $key, $value) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $key);
        if ($old == $value) {
                return false;
        } else {
            return update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $value);
        }
}
```

Or does Wordpress already do this check itself?

For reference I expect many of my post meta to remain unchanged - so the extra `get_post_meta` will be ok if i can bypas alot of `update_post_meta`'s...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update_post_meta()` uses [`update_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_metadata/) to update the post metadata, and if you call `update_post_meta()` without specifying the *fourth* parameter (i.e. `$prev_value`) — or that the value is empty, then yes, `update_metadata()` will check if the new value is the same as the current value in the database, and if so, the metadata will *not* be updated.

You can check [lines #195 to #202](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.8/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L195) in the `update_metadata()` source for the revelant code.

(*Update: Added the note below; above the "Additional Note" section.)*

And even if you specify the `$prev_value` (and set it to a non-empty value), MySQL will not update the metadata if `$prev_value` equals to the **new** value:

```
// Returns FALSE if current database value is 'hidden'...
update_post_meta( 123, '_visibility', 'hidden', 'hidden' );
```

### Additional Note: *Update metadata if exists; else, don't create new.*

`update_post_meta()` / `update_metadata()` will automatically add the metadata if an existing entry is not found in the database. So if you *don't* want that to happen, you can use [`metadata_exists()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/metadata_exists/) to prevent the automatic metadata creation; for example:

```
// 123 is the post ID.
if ( metadata_exists( 'post', 123, '_visibility' ) ) {
    update_post_meta( 123, '_visibility', 'hidden' );
}
```